# Choosing between full .NET framework and .NET Core as ASP.NET Core target?

Tags: asp.net, .net, visual-studio, asp.net-core, visual-studio-2017

I am extending a system that uses .NET 4.5 . I need:

1. The other projects to be able to reference my new .NET Core libraries.
2. My .NET Core projects to be able to reference our .NET 4 libraries.

Aside from the question of which one to target, I also have noticed that VS 2017 does not even give me the option to target .NET Core when creating a new project.[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

.net Core libraries are actually .net standard libraries. So when you create a .net standard library it can be referenced by full framework classes, but only if the version of .net standard you are using is correct. Sound confusing?

In simpler terms, take a look at this chart here https://github.com/dotnet/standard/blob/master/docs/versions.md

[image]

If your full framework classes are targeting .net framework 4.5, then to also be able to use them in .net core 1.0, you need to make your libraries use .net standard 1.1.

If you already have a full framework web app running, and you want to build the libraries in .net standard. The only reason you should really do so is if..

- You intend to convert your WebApp to .net core in the near future.
- You are building a class library that may be used in other .net core projects.

If you are sticking with full framework for your web app for the foreseeable, there isn't really any need to build things in .net standard (Especially if you are having to shoot for a very cut down version of the standard like 1.1).

As to why you can't "target" the framework when creating a .net core project. It's a known "bug" if you will. Or more so that the dropdown is redundant when you are creating a .net core project. It will simply use the latest version of the .net core SDK on your machine (By default).

Further reading :

- [.net Standard vs .net Core](http://dotnetcoretutorials.com/2017/01/13/net-standard-vs-net-core-whats-difference/)
- [Developing on 2 versions of .net core SDK](http://dotnetcoretutorials.com/2017/02/17/developing-two-versions-net-core-sdk-side-side/)

Comment: You're right, it doesn't matter what I choose for the drop-down when creating .NET Core projects.

Comment: What do you mean by "you need to make your libraries use .net standard 1.1"? How do I build in .NET standard, as opposed to say .NET 4.6 or .NET Core 1.0?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/core/tutorials/libraries

Comment: Okay. So I changed the csproj file manually and now VS shows the list of .NET Standard versions instead and I can reference my Core project from others. I still have one question: What am I missing when I target the latest .NET Standard as opposed to the latest .NET Core? Why doesn't everyone target some version of .NET Standard instead? For example, EF6 cannot be referenced in a Core application

Comment: Read this http://dotnetcoretutorials.com/2017/01/13/net-standard-vs-net-core-whats-difference/. .net standard is like an agreement between all .net platforms that they will be able to read it (Xamarin, .net core, .net framework etc). There is no reason XML Documents for example should work different across platforms, so they make them the same so you can build libraries that can be used on many platforms, not just one.

Comment: I understand that .NET Standard is only a standard, not a real thing. But is there no scenario where targeting .NET Core x.x is preferred to targeting the latest .NET Standard supported by x.x?

Comment: Well, when you are building a library only for .net core (e.g. It uses .net core specific things), then you can use .net core. But you won't be able to use it on a .net framework project etc.

Comment: Okay, so not every .NET Core library can be changed to target .NET standard.